# wanna control ardrone with ros, don't know the input

Tags: control, ros, quadcopter, node, subscribe

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Im now using the ardrone_autonomy(instead ardrone sdk)
now i want to create a new node to publish topic and make the ardrone node to subscribe, and the topic will be some command that make drone to hover or something like pid control.   ardrone_autonomy read me file only mentioned the commands to ardrone which is :
" The drone will take off,land or emergency stop/reset by publishing an Empty ROS messages to the following topics: ardrone/takeoff, ardrone/land and ardrone/reset  repectively.  in order to fly the drone after takeoff, you can publish a message of type geometry_msgs::Twist to the cmd_vel topic."  . And those topic only allow me to control the drone with position control.
in general case, when controlling quadrotor, we may have 4 inputs like u1,u2,u3,u4, those straightly control the degree of each angles.
Didn't I find the right input to control ardrone? if i did , plz tell me where those variables are, and how to change them to control ardrone's attitude.
Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/153976/wanna-control-ardrone-with-ros,-don%27t-know-the-input/) by [ad26kr](https://answers.ros.org/users/14696/ad26kr/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2014-04-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

https://github.com/AutonomyLab/ardrone_autonomy/

---

Originally posted by [ad26kr](https://answers.ros.org/users/14696/ad26kr/) with karma: 16 on 2014-04-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0